# How did the Clones find Jedi Investigators during Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)), Season 2 Episode 11: Lost Lightsaber, we are introduced to an elder Jedi named Tera Sinube, who is a Jedi Investigator that helped Padawan Ahsoka Tano to recover her lightsaber, which was stolen by a thief named Bannamu, after this point we don't hear anything about Tera Sinube anymore.

So my question is, how did the Clone Troopers find all the Jedi Investigators during Order 66 considering they are scattered around Coruscant helping the police. According to Wookieepedia they don't have any clone troopers with them so were they all in the Clone Wars or at the Jedi Temple during the Purge. It sounds like they are alive living in exile since they probably felt disturbances in the Force like Yoda did in Revenge of the Sith

Comment: One assumes that all Jedi on Coruscant were recalled to aid the defence of the Temple. This would explain their near-total destruction as an Order.

Comment: Not necessarily. See WHY Yoda and Obi lived in exile and stayed there. To watch over the twins and wait for them to be ready. The others, like Kanan are often drawn to troubles by the force and even more so as many don't have as elaborate reasons as Yoda and obi or a mental trauma like Kanan try to help instinctively (as it has been ingrained into them since their youth).....and that raises the interest of the inquisitors, the clones and a specific Vader. So I can see most of them die because of that.

Answer (score 8):

While we do not have definite answer what happened to Tera Sinube, it is safe to say that while some Jedi did survive initial strike of Order 66 (and didn't return to Temple on fake beacon), most of them were killed in months, sometimes years to come. So far, there is no evidence that anyone except Yoda was alive when Battle of Yavin happened.

Typical example would be [Luminara Unduli](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luminara_Unduli), she was Jedi Master but could not escape capture and later execution. People often forget that bulk of Jedi were simply far less capable than Yoda and Obi-Wan Kenobi. They could defeat few clone troopers but not dozens of them, and if they didn't have helpful network of underground connections they would not be able to hide for long .

Before Order 66, Jedi didn't have much reason to hide or to associate with criminal elements of society. They were military leaders and diplomats, most of them proud about their abilities and rank. Therefore, they were (with few exceptions) totally unprepared for life of outlaws when tragedy struck them.